# Extending the size of an image by padding the borders with 1s

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to extend the size my image using MATLAB.  For example, I have an image of `397x450` I want to make it into `600x600` where I place the original image in the middle, but all of the new elements have to be `1` i.e. 397x450 elements will remain the same as original image and will be placed in the middle of the output image, and rest of the elements in `600x600` image will be made `1`.

Is there an efficient way to do this in MATLAB?

Comment: I've edited your post to better represent what you're really after.  You're after padding the image with 1s, not resizing the image.  Please let me know if my edits are agreeable.  If not, I'll revert back to your old version, but I think this better represents what you're really after.

Comment: @rayryeng Yeah thanks this looks much better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to extend the image so that original contents are in the middle, you can calculate the middle of the output image which is initialized to all 1s, then make sure you place the image so that it spans the width and height of the original one.  This will get messy if you have input images that are even in dimension... but assuming you have **odd** dimensions, do this:

```
rows_out = 600; cols_out = 600;
out = ones(rows_out, cols_out, size(im,3));

rows_in = size(im,1); cols_in = size(im,2);
rows_half = floor(rows_in/2); cols_half = floor(cols_in/2);

out_half_rows = floor(rows_out/2); out_half_cols = floor(cols_out/2);

out(out_half_rows-rows_half : out_half_rows+rows_half, ...
    out_half_cols-cols_half : out_half_cols+cols_half, :) = im;
```

As an additional check, you can check to see if your image has even rows or columns by checking the remainder of dividing by 2 and if there is a reminder, we can remove the last row and/or column for example:

```
rows_in = size(im,1) - (mod(size(im,1),2) + 1);
cols_in = size(im,2) - (mod(size(im,2),2) + 1); 
im = im(1:rows_in, 1:cols_in, :);
```

Take note that the above code will remove the last two rows and two columns for the case of it being odd.

---

Here's an example with a 256 x 256 dark square on a 600 x 600 white background:

```
out = ones(600,600);
im = zeros(256,256);
```

Using the above checks to ensure odd image sizes, we get:

[image]

Comment: I want to move my original image somewhere in the middle

Comment: @Joker - That wasn't in your original problem.  Do we look like mind readers?

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
result = zeros(600);
result(102:498,75:524) = image;
```

Comment: Yes but this will only increase the dimensions towards right and down.I want to move my original image somewhere in the middle